# Libusb race condition using asynchronous I/O

Tags: c, libusb

I'm using libusb to communicate with a Philips ISP1362 configured as a USB device.  I am able to successfully loopback data using Synchronous I/O without any problems.  For some reason when using Asynchronous I/O there appears to be a race condition.

I am transferring 64-byte packets using back-to-back OUT-IN transfers.  Occasionally when I run my program libusb throws a timeout error and some of the loopback data is lost.  When analyzing the USB bus using my Beagle 12 I can see the OUT-IN transactions are out of order (i.e. OUT-OUT-IN-TIMEOUT) when it should be (OUT-IN-OUT-IN).

**Update** The transfers are appearing out of order in the callback function which is strange because they are not coinciding with what is actually on the bus analyzer.

Example 1: (IN-OUT-IN-OUT)

```
main(): submitting transfer 0, endpoint 1
main(): submitting transfer 1, endpoint 82
main(): submitting transfer 2, endpoint 1
main(): submitting transfer 3, endpoint 82
xfr_cb(): count 0, status = 0, endpoint = 82, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
xfr_cb(): count 1, status = 0, endpoint = 1, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
xfr_cb(): count 2, status = 0, endpoint = 82, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
xfr_cb(): count 3, status = 0, endpoint = 1, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
completed
```

Example 2: (OUT-IN-IN-OUT)

```
main(): submitting transfer 0, endpoint 1
main(): submitting transfer 1, endpoint 82
main(): submitting transfer 2, endpoint 1
main(): submitting transfer 3, endpoint 82
xfr_cb(): count 0, status = 0, endpoint = 1, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
xfr_cb(): count 1, status = 0, endpoint = 82, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
xfr_cb(): count 2, status = 0, endpoint = 82, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
xfr_cb(): count 3, status = 0, endpoint = 1, actual_length = 64, completed = 0
completed
```

Below is a screenshot from the analyzer:

[image: Beagle 12 Capture]

Below is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

/* Specify VENDOR_ID and PRODUCT_ID for device */
#define VENDOR_ID   0x0471
#define PRODUCT_ID  0x3630

/* Define number of bytes to transfer */
#define EP_SIZE 64               // bytes
#define TRANSFERS 4              // number of transfers
#define BYTES EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS
#define TIMEOUT 3*1000           // milliseconds

/* Use a global variable to keep the device handle */
static struct libusb_device_handle *devh = NULL;

/* use a global variable to keep the context */
static struct libusb_context *usb_context = NULL;

/* count variable */
int count = 0;

/* The Endpoint addresses are hard-coded.  You should use libusb -v to find
 * the values corresponding to device
 */
static int ep_in  = 0x82;
static int ep_out = 0x01;

void xfr_cb(struct libusb_transfer *transfer )
{
  int *completed = transfer->user_data;

  /* callback - This is called after the transfer has been received by libusb */
  fprintf(stderr, "xfr_cb(): count %d, status = %d, endpoint = %x, actual_length = %d, completed = %d\n",
          count,
          transfer->status,
          transfer->endpoint,
          transfer->actual_length,
          *completed);
  if (transfer->status != LIBUSB_TRANSFER_COMPLETED)
  {
    /* Error! */
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", libusb_error_name((int)transfer->status));
  }

  if (count == TRANSFERS-1)
    *completed = 1;
  count++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int ep_addr;
  int completed = 0;
  unsigned char *buf;
  size_t length = 64;
  int n;
  int i;
  int rc;

  /* Initialize libusb */
  rc = libusb_init(NULL);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Initializing libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Set debugging output to max level */
  libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

  /* Look for a specific device and open it */
  devh = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
  if (!devh)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* allocate memory */
  buf = malloc(length);

  /* start with OUT transfer */
  ep_addr = ep_out;

  /* queue up alternating OUT-IN transfers */
  for (i = 0; i < TRANSFERS; i++)
  {
    /* fill the buffer with incrementing data */
    for (n = 0; n < EP_SIZE; n++)
    {
      buf[n] = i+n;
    }

    /* Set up the transfer object */
    struct libusb_transfer *transfer;
    transfer = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
    libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer, devh, ep_addr, buf, EP_SIZE, xfr_cb, &completed, TIMEOUT); /* callback data = &completed */

    /* Submit the transfer object */
    libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);
    fprintf(stderr, "main(): submitting transfer %d, endpoint %x\n", i, ep_addr);

    /* alternate writing and reading for loopback */
    ep_addr = (ep_addr == ep_out) ? ep_in : ep_out;
  }

  /* Handle Events */
  while (!completed)
  {
    rc = libusb_handle_events_completed(NULL, &completed);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
      if (rc == LIBUSB_ERROR_INTERRUPTED)
        continue;
      fprintf(stderr, "Transfer Error: %s", libusb_error_name(rc));
      continue;
    }
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "completed\n");

  /* Release the interface */
  libusb_release_interface(devh, 0);


  /* Close the device handle */
  if (devh)
    libusb_close(devh);


out:
  if (devh)
  {
    libusb_close(devh);
  }
  libusb_exit(NULL);

  return rc;
}
```

**Update 2**  I successfully eliminated the timeout.  The cause of the libusb timeout is because the Host was sending two consecutive OUT transactions intermittently on the bus.

Analyzer screenshot:

[image]

The following is the working code (no timeouts).  Ran these thousands of times with no issues

```
static void LIBUSB_CALL xfr_cb(struct libusb_transfer *transfer )
{
  int *completed = transfer->user_data;
  unsigned char *wbuf, *rbuf;
  size_t length = 64;

  fprintf(stderr, "xfr_cb(): status = %d, endpoint = %x, actual_length = %d\n",
          transfer->status,
          transfer->endpoint,
          transfer->actual_length);

  *completed = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const struct libusb_version *version;
  int ep_addr;
  int completed = 0;
  unsigned char *buf, *wbuf1, *wbuf2, *rbuf1, *rbuf2;
  size_t length = 64;
  int n;
  int m;
  int i;
  int rc;

  /* Get libusb version */
  version = libusb_get_version();
  fprintf(stderr, "libusb version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", version->major, version->minor, version->micro, version->nano);

  /* Initialize libusb */
  rc = libusb_init(NULL);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Initializing libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Set debugging output to max level */
  libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

  /* Look for a specific device and open it */
  handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
  if (!handle)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* claim interface */
  rc = libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error claiming interface.\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* allocate memory */
  wbuf1 = malloc(length);
  wbuf2 = malloc(length);
  rbuf1 = malloc(length);
  rbuf2 = malloc(length);

  /* fill the buffer with incrementing data */
  for (n = 0; n < EP_SIZE; n++)
    wbuf1[n] = n;

  for (m = 0; m < EP_SIZE; m++)
    wbuf2[m] = m+1;

  struct libusb_transfer *transfer1;
  struct libusb_transfer *transfer2;
  struct libusb_transfer *transfer3;
  struct libusb_transfer *transfer4;

  /* Set up the transfer object */
  transfer1 = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  transfer2 = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  transfer3 = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  transfer4 = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer1, handle, ep_out, wbuf1, EP_SIZE, xfr_cb, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer2, handle, ep_in, rbuf1, EP_SIZE,  xfr_cb, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer3, handle, ep_out, wbuf2, EP_SIZE, xfr_cb, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer4, handle, ep_in, rbuf2, EP_SIZE,  xfr_cb, &completed, TIMEOUT); /* callback data = &completed */

  /* Submit the transfers */
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer1);
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer2);
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer3);
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer4);

  /* Handle Events */
  while (!completed)
  {
    rc = libusb_handle_events_completed(NULL, &completed);
    if (rc != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Transfer Error: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
      break;
    }
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "completed\n");

  //* Release the interface */
  libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);

  /* Close the device handle */
  if (handle)
    libusb_close(handle);

out:
  if (handle)
  {
    libusb_close(handle);
  }
  libusb_exit(NULL);

  return rc;
}
```

Changing the code as follows (i.e. callback = NULL for transfer 1-3) re-creates intermittent duplicate transactions, as shown in the screenshots.

```
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer1, handle, ep_out, wbuf1, EP_SIZE, NULL, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer2, handle, ep_in, rbuf1, EP_SIZE,  NULL, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer3, handle, ep_out, wbuf2, EP_SIZE, NULL, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer4, handle, ep_in, rbuf2, EP_SIZE,  xfr_cb, &completed, TIMEOUT); /* callback data = &completed */
```

I honestly don't understand why the loop would cause race conditions based on their documentation and examples.  Queueing up multiple transfers is actually suggested in one of the libusb examples (sam3u_benchmark.c) and also demonstrated (using loops) in the following .pdfs.

See asynchronous I/O sections:

https://www.socallinuxexpo.org/sites/default/files/presentations/scale_2017_usb.pdf
http://www.signal11.us/oss/elc2014/elc_2014_usb_0.pdf

From my understanding, the use of *libusb_handle_events_completed(NULL, &completed)* is supposed to resolve synchronization issues.  Am I misunderstanding something?
See *libusb_handle_events() from multiple threads*
http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/libusb_mtasync.html

-"This is why libusb-1.0.9 introduces the new libusb_handle_events_timeout_completed() and libusb_handle_events_completed() functions, which handles doing the completion check for you after they have acquired the lock:"

What they need are crystal clear examples of how to use their API if this is the case.

I can add more event checking but something does not seem right here.

**Update 3:**  See accepted answer.

Comment: When I last used libusb for usb access I had a chance to look at the source code, and it lacks all kinds of synchronization code.  You have to provide it externally, in case more than one process/thread is going to use the same device.  As this response is far from complete at all, I post it as a comment only.

Comment: That's good to know.  I appreciate the heads up.

Comment: I have no experience with libusb. But the async API docs make pretty clear that its is a thin interface layer that initiates an OS async IO operation and calls you back when that's complete. How consecutive block transfers work (as you have coded yours) is up to the OS. It's likely all the transfers started by the for loop are racing with each other, so the result is pot luck.

Comment: I provided an update.  I understand what you're saying.  This seems to contradict their documentation though.  Here's the link to where they advise queueing multiple transfers in advance https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/examples/sam3u_benchmark.c.  Besides a loop is there another fashion?

Comment: I'm starting to think the folks who wrote those pdf's didn't understand the API that well, as I didn't.  Using a loop to queue transfers, especially a large amount, seems to be wrong approach and can lead to issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started reading the documentation in the libusb source code and understood what was happening.

Particularly the section about how libusb deals with packet sizes:
http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/libusb_packetoverflow.html

After reading that it clicked for me and I found two ways to accomplish a loopback test with large data size using asynchronous I/O.

The first way is submitting two transfers consecutively with transfer->buffer containing the entire data structure (i.e. total bytes to send and receive).  The second way is submitting the two transfers with transfer->buffer containing wMaxPacketSize (e.g. 64-bytes) and having the out and in callback functions submit additional transfers to transceive the rest of the data.

For the second case, extra code needed to be added to keep track of the number of transfers and to set the completed signal when finished.  The OUT-IN packet interleaving is handled by libusb and the OS - which was the part I didn't realize.  In other words, not every OUT-IN transfer needed to be specified and queued individually.

Here is the asynchronous code along with the transfer rates to my USB device (ISP1362).  My USB device controller is an FPGA coded in pure SystemVerilog.

Note:  Regarding the transfer rates, I only have double-buffering enabled on BULK_EP_IN.  I am assuming the IN-NAK's (# POLL) and transfer rate would improve in the second approach if double-buffering was enabled on BULK_EP_OUT.  So this may not be a fair comparison due to device configuration.

First approach: ~1.161 MB/s (~9.288 Mb/s)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include </usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

/* Specify VENDOR_ID and PRODUCT_ID for device */
#define VENDOR_ID   0x0471
#define PRODUCT_ID  0x3630

/* Define number of bytes to transfer */
#define EP_SIZE 64                       // bytes
#define TRANSFERS 1024*768*3/EP_SIZE     // number of transfers
#define TIMEOUT 10*1000                  // milliseconds

/* Use a global variable to keep the device handle */
static struct libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;

/* count variables */
unsigned int count = 0;
unsigned int count_in = 0;
unsigned int count_out = 0;

/* The Endpoint addresses are hard-coded.  You should use libusb -v to find
 * the values corresponding to device
 */
static int ep_in  = 0x82;
static int ep_out = 0x01;

/* Write and Read buffers */
unsigned char wbuf[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];
unsigned char wbuf_tmp[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];
unsigned char rbuf[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];
unsigned char rbuf_tmp[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];

static void LIBUSB_CALL xfr_cb_out(struct libusb_transfer *transfer )
{
  memcpy(wbuf+count_out*EP_SIZE, transfer->buffer, EP_SIZE);
}

static void LIBUSB_CALL xfr_cb_in(struct libusb_transfer *transfer )
{
  int *completed = transfer->user_data;
  memcpy(rbuf+count_in*EP_SIZE, transfer->buffer, EP_SIZE);

  count_in++;  // one transfer complete
  if (count_in < TRANSFERS)
    *completed = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const struct libusb_version *version;
  int completed = 0;
  size_t length = 64;
  int n;
  int m;
  int rc;

  /* Get libusb version */
  version = libusb_get_version();
  fprintf(stderr, "libusb version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", version->major, version->minor, version->micro, version->nano);

  /* Initialize libusb */
  rc = libusb_init(NULL);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Initializing libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Set debugging output to max level */
  libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

  /* Look for a specific device and open it */
  handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
  if (!handle)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* claim interface */
  rc = libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error claiming interface.\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* fill the buffer with incrementing data */
  for (n = 0; n < TRANSFERS; n++)
  {
    for (m = 0; m < EP_SIZE; m++)
    {
      wbuf_tmp[m+n*EP_SIZE] = m+n;
    }
  }

  struct libusb_transfer *transfer;
  transfer = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer, handle, ep_out, wbuf_tmp, EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS, xfr_cb_out, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);

  transfer = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer, handle, ep_in, rbuf_tmp, EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS, xfr_cb_in, &completed, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);

  /* Handle Events */
  while (!completed)
  {
    rc = libusb_handle_events_completed(NULL, &completed);
    if (rc != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Transfer Error: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
      break;
    }
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "completed\n");

  int res;
  res = memcmp(rbuf, wbuf, sizeof(wbuf));
  if (res != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "miscompare\n");
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "success\n");

  //* Release the interface */
  libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);

  /* Close the device handle */
  if (handle)
    libusb_close(handle);

out:
  if (handle)
  {
    libusb_close(handle);
  }
  libusb_exit(NULL);

  return rc;
}
```

[image]

Second approach: ~755.9 KB/s (~6.047 Mb/s)

```
include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include </usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

/* Specify VENDOR_ID and PRODUCT_ID for device */
#define VENDOR_ID   0x0471
#define PRODUCT_ID  0x3630

/* Define number of bytes to transfer */
#define EP_SIZE 64                       // bytes
#define TRANSFERS 1024*768*3/EP_SIZE     // number of transfers
#define TIMEOUT 10*1000                  // milliseconds

/* Use a global variable to keep the device handle */
static struct libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;

/* count variables */
unsigned int count = 0;
unsigned int count_in = 0;
unsigned int count_out = 0;

/* The Endpoint addresses are hard-coded.  You should use libusb -v to find
 * the values corresponding to device
 */
static int ep_in  = 0x82;
static int ep_out = 0x01;

/* Write and Read buffers */
unsigned char wbuf[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];
unsigned char *wbuf_tmp;
unsigned char rbuf[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];
unsigned char rbuf_tmp[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];

static void LIBUSB_CALL xfr_cb_out(struct libusb_transfer *transfer )
{
  memcpy(wbuf+count_out*EP_SIZE, transfer->buffer, EP_SIZE);

  count_out++;  // one transfer complete
  if (count_out < TRANSFERS)
  {
    transfer->buffer = ++wbuf_tmp;
    libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);
  }
}

static void LIBUSB_CALL xfr_cb_in(struct libusb_transfer *transfer )
{
  int *completed = transfer->user_data;
  memcpy(rbuf+count_in*EP_SIZE, transfer->buffer, EP_SIZE);

  count_in++;  // one transfer complete
  if (count_in < TRANSFERS)
    libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);
  else
    *completed = 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const struct libusb_version *version;
  int completed = 0;
  size_t length = 64;
  int n;
  int rc;

  /* Get libusb version */
  version = libusb_get_version();
  fprintf(stderr, "libusb version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", version->major, version->minor, version->micro, version->nano);

  /* Initialize libusb */
  rc = libusb_init(NULL);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Initializing libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Set debugging output to max level */
  libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

  /* Look for a specific device and open it */
  handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
  if (!handle)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* claim interface */
  rc = libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error claiming interface.\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* allocate memory */
  wbuf_tmp = malloc(length*TRANSFERS);

  /* fill the buffer with incrementing data */
  for (n = 0; n < EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS; n++)
  {
    wbuf_tmp[n] = n;
  }

  struct libusb_transfer *transfer;
  transfer = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer, handle, ep_out, wbuf_tmp, EP_SIZE, xfr_cb_out, NULL, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);

  transfer = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
  libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer, handle, ep_in, rbuf_tmp, EP_SIZE, xfr_cb_in, &completed, TIMEOUT);
  libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);

  /* Handle Events */
  while (!completed)
  {
    rc = libusb_handle_events_completed(NULL, &completed);
    if (rc != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Transfer Error: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
      break;
    }
  }

  fprintf(stderr, "completed\n");

  int res;
  res = memcmp(rbuf, wbuf, sizeof(wbuf));
  if (res != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "miscompare\n");
  else
    fprintf(stderr, "success\n");

  //* Release the interface */
  libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);

  /* Close the device handle */
  if (handle)
    libusb_close(handle);

out:
  if (handle)
  {
    libusb_close(handle);
  }
  libusb_exit(NULL);

  return rc;
}
```

[image]

Comment: hello @mrbean, this is an old thread, but, just a quick question if you're still around:
You compare 2 approaches, your throughput results being:
1) ~1.161 MB/s (~9.288 Mb/s)
2) ~755.9 MB/s (~6.047 Mb/s)

How sall I read these numbers: is the first the read and the second the write throughput?

I cannot understand how it is possible that resubmitting so many time those small transfers could lead to a x700 gain in performance, given the CPU is much more involved in the second case.

Did you figure out why is is like this?

Comment: Also max theoretical USB2 throughput is 480Mbit/s. Are you using USB3?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @sonatique Looks like I made a typo.  The actual speed was ~755.9 KB/s (KB instead of MB).  The speed is also at the very bottom of the screenshots, in the lower left-hand corner. Also this was with full speed USB where the theoretical maximum is 12 Mbit/s. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**  See accepted answer.

The following is an example using Synchronous I/O.  I had a lot of trouble getting the transactions to come out in the expected order using Asynchronous I/O.  I assume this was due to transfers racing with each other as @Gene had mentioned.

The main gripe I have about the libusb API is the lack of examples to illustrate proper use.  The API would lead someone to believe that asynchronous transactions are placed on the bus in the order they are "submitted" and from what I gather this is not true.  This functionality would be fine for submitting transactions with all the same packet TOKEN (i.e. OUT or IN).

The following code works for large bulk transfers.

Using Synchronous I/O

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

/* Change VENDOR_ID and PRODUCT_ID depending on device */
#define VENDOR_ID   0x0471
#define PRODUCT_ID  0x3630

/* Define number of bytes to transfer */
#define BYTES 1024*768*3 // bytes
#define EP_SIZE 64       // bytes
#define TIMEOUT 5*1000   // milliseconds

/* Use a global variable to keep the device handle */
static struct libusb_device_handle *devh = NULL;

/* The Endpoint addresses are hard-coded.  You should use libusb -v to find
 * the values corresponding to device
 */
static int ep_in_addr  = 0x82;
static int ep_out_addr = 0x01;

int write_chars(unsigned char * data, int length)
{
  /* To send a char to the device simply initiate a bulk_transfer to the Endpoint
   * with the address ep_out_addr.
   */
  int actual_length;

  int rc = libusb_bulk_transfer(devh, ep_out_addr, data, length, &actual_length, TIMEOUT);

  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while sending char: %d\n", rc);
    return -1;
  }

  return actual_length;
}

int read_chars(unsigned char * data, int length)
{
  /* To receive characters from the device initiate a bulk_transfer to the Entpoint
   * with address ep_in_addr
   */
  int actual_length;

  int rc = libusb_bulk_transfer(devh, ep_in_addr, data, length, &actual_length, TIMEOUT);

  if (rc == LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT)
  {
    printf("timeout (%d)\n", actual_length);
    return -1;
  }
  else if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while waiting for char: %d\n", rc);
    return -1;
  }

  return actual_length;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int rc;

  /* Initialize libusb */
  rc = libusb_init(NULL);

  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Initializing libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Set debugging output to max level */
  libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

  /* Look for a specific device and open it */
  devh = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
  if (!devh)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* We can now start sending or receiving data to the device */
  unsigned char buf[BYTES];
  unsigned char rbuf[EP_SIZE];
  int len;
  int n;
  int l;
  int res;

  // fill buffer
  for (n = 0; n < BYTES; n++)
  {
    buf[n] = 0x00+n;
  }

  // loopback data, write-read
  for (l = 0; l < BYTES/EP_SIZE; l++)
  {
    len = write_chars(buf+l*EP_SIZE, EP_SIZE);
    len = read_chars(rbuf, EP_SIZE);
    res = memcmp(rbuf, buf+l*EP_SIZE, sizeof(rbuf));
    if (res != 0)
      fprintf(stderr, "Miscompare: block %d\n", l);
  }

  libusb_release_interface(devh, 0);

out:
  if (devh)
  {
    libusb_close(devh);
  }
  libusb_exit(NULL);

  return rc;
}
```

Using Asynchronous and Synchronous together (i.e. OUT is submitted Asynchronously and IN is Synchronous)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include </usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h>

/* Specify VENDOR_ID and PRODUCT_ID for device */
#define VENDOR_ID   0x0471
#define PRODUCT_ID  0x3630

/* Define number of bytes to transfer */
#define EP_SIZE 64                       // bytes
#define TRANSFERS 1024*768*3/EP_SIZE     // number of transfers
#define BYTES EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS
#define TIMEOUT 15*1000                  // milliseconds

/* Use a global variable to keep the device handle */
static struct libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;

/* count variable */
unsigned int count_out = 0;

/* The Endpoint addresses are hard-coded.  You should use libusb -v to find
 * the values corresponding to device
 */
static int ep_in  = 0x82;
static int ep_out = 0x01;

unsigned char rbuf[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];
unsigned char wbuf[EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS];

static void LIBUSB_CALL xfr_cb_out(struct libusb_transfer *transfer )
{
  memcpy(wbuf+count_out*EP_SIZE, transfer->buffer, EP_SIZE);
  count_out++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const struct libusb_version *version;
  unsigned char *buf, *rbuf_tmp;
  size_t length = 64;
  int n;
  int i;
  int rc;

  /* Get libusb version */
  version = libusb_get_version();
  fprintf(stderr, "libusb version: %d.%d.%d.%d\n", version->major, version->minor, version->micro, version->nano);

  /* Initialize libusb */
  rc = libusb_init(NULL);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error Initializing libusb: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
    exit(1);
  }

  /* Set debugging output to max level */
  libusb_set_debug(NULL, 3);

  /* Look for a specific device and open it */
  handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(NULL, VENDOR_ID, PRODUCT_ID);
  if (!handle)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error finding USB device\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* claim interface */
  rc = libusb_claim_interface(handle, 0);
  if (rc < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error claiming interface.\n");
    goto out;
  }

  /* allocate memory */
  buf = malloc(length*TRANSFERS);

  /* fill the buffer with incrementing data */
  for (n = 0; n < EP_SIZE*TRANSFERS; n++)
  {
    buf[n] = n;
  }

  /* allocate memory */
  rbuf_tmp = malloc(length);

  /* set up alternating OUT-IN transfers */
  for (i = 0; i < TRANSFERS; i++)
  {
    struct libusb_transfer *transfer;
    transfer = libusb_alloc_transfer(0);
    libusb_fill_bulk_transfer(transfer, handle, ep_out, buf+i, EP_SIZE, xfr_cb_out, NULL, TIMEOUT);
    libusb_submit_transfer(transfer);

    int actual_length;
    int rc = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle, ep_in, rbuf_tmp, EP_SIZE, &actual_length, TIMEOUT);
    if (rc != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Transfer Error: %s\n", libusb_error_name(rc));
      break;
    }

    memcpy(rbuf+i*EP_SIZE, rbuf_tmp, EP_SIZE);
  }
  fprintf(stderr, "completed\n");

  int res;
  res = memcmp(rbuf, wbuf, sizeof(wbuf));
  if (res != 0)
    fprintf(stderr, "miscompare\n");

  //* Release the interface */
  libusb_release_interface(handle, 0);

  /* Close the device handle */
  if (handle)
    libusb_close(handle);

out:
  if (handle)
  {
    libusb_close(handle);
  }
  libusb_exit(NULL);

  return rc;
}
```

The above code was an experiment to see if performance increased.  Interestingly, the speed difference between the two was negligible.

The version of libusb was 1.0.17.10830